# Create chart in SPA(Aurelia) with MVVM pattern

Tags: mvvm, chart.js, aurelia

I've an Aurelia app on which I've to display some charts. I'm quite familiar with the MVVM pattern in .Net, but not in javascript.

I've installed `Chart.js` in my app. In my viewModel, I've imported it (`import { Chart } from 'chart.js';`).

In my view I've a prepared a Canva:

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Now, how am I supposed to generate this chart? Because for me it's kind of a view issue for what I create, so should I create a `<script>` tag and put the creation code in it? How do I bind with the data that will come from the view models?

Do I need to do some `<require from="..:"></require>` in the view?

Or should I instantiate the chart from the ViewModel?(in that case, when should I create it since in the constructor, the dom element will already exist, and in my opinion this break the loosely coupled approach).

Thank you!

**EDIT**

Here is currently what I've after @valichek answer:

ViewModel:

```
import { Aurelia, inject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { Router, RouterConfiguration } from 'aurelia-router';
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
import { log } from "../services/log";

export class ClanChest {
    viewCanva: HTMLCanvasElement;
    constructor() {
    }

    public attached() {
        log.info('Starting to attach');
        var myChart = new Chart(this.viewCanva, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
                datasets: [{
                    label: '# of Votes',
                    data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });

        log.info('Finished');
    }

}
```

View:

```
<template>
    <h1>ClanChest</h1>
    <canvas ref="viewCanva" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</template>
```

The code is executed, I've no errors, but so far I've nothing displayed, the canva has been resized to 0x0 and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two places in VM: `bind` (data for the component are available) and `attached` (ready for DOM changes)

You can read more about component lifecycle here http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/creating-components/3

Also there is `ref` attribute that could be useful, when accessing the `<canvas />`

http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-basics/5

Update: I have created own working example:

components/chartjs/chart.js

```
import {containerless} from 'aurelia-framework';
import ChartJs from 'chart.js'

@containerless()
export class Chart {

  container;

  constructor() {

  }

  attached() {


  this.myChart = new ChartJs(this.container, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
      datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  });


  }

}
```

components/chartjs/chart.html:

```
<template>
  <canvas ref="container" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</template>
```

somewhere on page:

```
<require from="components/chartjs/chart"></require>
<chart></chart>
```

Note: this is just example, maybe you will need some optimizations, like checking and avoiding memory leaks if present when component is re-attached

Comment: So you would put all the logic for the chart inside the VM? Ref is to reference VM from the view, no?

Comment: yes, in that way you follow aurelia way. Ref is to reference `canvas` element in VM

Comment: Do you have just an example for the ref? How do I use it in the VM? There is no example in your link

Comment: I think I found an example, but currently, this is not working, I've no errors, but the chart isn't displayed. I debugged the code, and the differents elements(viewCanva, myChart) are correctly filled with something. 
Any idea what is missing?

Comment: In official `Chart.js` docs  `import Chart from 'chart.js'`, looks different from your example

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce. But why are you importing "ChartJs" and not "Chart"? Is this the difference? Because on their documentation I find the `Import Chart`

Comment: Now I've an error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: chart_js_1.default is not a constructor`when calling the `new Chart(...)`(both with using Chart our ChartJs as an import

Comment: I tried to execute the new Chart method in the browser, I've the same result, I receive a  `Chart.Controller` in return, my canvas get sized to 0x0px, and nothing is displayed.

Comment: ChartJs is the "local" name you use in VM, I have Chart for VM, so I had to change import to `ChartJs`.

Comment: I think that you just have wrong import syntax,  change it to `import Chart from 'chart.js'`, without curly braces

Comment: Yes, it's my current version, but I've the TypeError then.

Comment: Not sure it helps, but my whole code is on github: https://github.com/jgrossrieder/CR-ClanGate you can find the issue here: https://github.com/jgrossrieder/CR-ClanGate/tree/master/ClanGate.Web/ClientApp/app/components/clan-chest

Comment: I have js app, so suppose there is smth wrong when using typescript

Comment: Try to log what is Chart, maybe you have some webpack building issue

Comment: I've ran webpack manually(`webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js`). `Chart`is `undefined`when I log it. Not sure to understand why.

Comment: With `import {Chart}   from 'chart.js';` if I log Chart, I get `function (item, config) {
  this.controller = new Chart.Controller(item, config, this);
  return this.controller;
 }` So I think this is the correct way to import the ChartJS. Like this I don't have any error, but I still don't have any Chart displayed.